# Make MUI Button grow in width with transition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, css-transitions

So we have this custom ToggleButton, and we have a case where text inside it changes based on some state changes. The issue is that that grow in width is abrupt, how to transition that with ease?

Here's my component so far:

```
import {
  type Theme, ToggleButton as MUIToggleButton, ToggleButtonProps, useTheme,
} from '@mui/material';
import { IWithSeleniumAttribute } from '../../../../interfaces';
import { Typography } from '../../../index';

export interface ITabProps extends ToggleButtonProps, IWithSeleniumAttribute {
  typographyDataSelenium?: string;
}

const buildSX = (theme: Theme) => ({
  // our styles here
});

const Tab = (props: ITabProps) => {
  const {
    typographyDataSelenium,
    children,
    sx = [],
    ...restProps
  } = props;

  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <MUIToggleButton
      sx={[
        buildSX(theme),
        ...(Array.isArray(sx) ? sx : [sx]),
      ]}
      {...restProps}
    >
      <Typography data-selenium={typographyDataSelenium}>
        {children}
      </Typography>
    </MUIToggleButton>
  );
};

export default Tab;
```